# Calling Java from PHP with arguments as arrays

Tags: java, php, arrays, eval

I am trying to call Java from PHP via eval and pass an array as an argument.

PHP code:

```
$var1 = 'test';
$var2 = array("one","two","three");
exec("java HelloWorldApp " . $var1 . " " . $var2 . " 2>&1", $output);
print_r( $output );
print_r( $output[2]);
```

Java code:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
        System.out.println(args[0]); 
        System.out.println(args[1]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot extract array's elements from the 2nd argument in Java: **it takes the input array as a string "Array**" and not as an array. The PHP output is

```
Array ( [0] => Hello World! [1] => test [2] => Array ) Array
```

How can I pass an array to Java and access its elements?

Thanks

Comment: The best way to do this is using JSON. You can read and write json in almost every language. Using that, you can convert your arrays to json, pass them, then convert them to array again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct mapping between an array-like data structure in PHP and Java.  If possible, you could convert the PHP array to a serialized Java object array / ArrayList, etc., but such a library may either not exist or would have to be installed and included.

Instead it would be much easier to use JSON.

```
$var2 = json_encode($var2);
```

Unfortunately, Java has no native JSON support.  Two popular Java libraries for JSON are [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).  They are both able to easily parse JSON strings into Java data structures.

If all you want is a string representation of the array items, you could do `implode(',', $var2)`

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Will I have any problems in passing huge JSON objects of approx. 5,000 elements?

Comment: @user2723490  I don't see why, but in that case perhaps you will want to use a file or a database -- especially if that number can continue to grow